# Why does CloudKit JS "sortBy" return a different order on Safari?

Tags: knockout.js, cloudkit-js

I'm trying to mirror a high scores leader board from my app on a webpage. Following an old [raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/997-cloudkit-js-tutorial-for-ios) I am using CloudKit JS and Knockout to accomplish this.
Naturally, I want to sort by scores from highest to lowest.

The example code in the tutorial uses:

```
var query = { recordType: 'CD_FinalScore', sortBy: [{ fieldName: 'CD_score'}] };
```

(Of course, I am plugging in my recordType and fieldName for the example ones.) This did not give me the results I wanted, so I added a sort method on the records fetched by the query:

```
self.items(records.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}));
```

This gives me the results I want on Firefox but not on Safari (where the order is the inverse).
My gut tells me that I need to focus on the query signature.
Can someone tell me what I've done wrong or incompletely? Thanks!
For reference, the complete Knockout view model code is here:

```
function LeaderboardViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.fields = ko.observable('');
    self.fields.CD_score = ko.observable('');
    self.fields.CD_userName = ko.observable('');
    self.fields.CD_submitDate = ko.observable('');

    self.fetchRecords = function() {
      var query = { recordType: 'CD_FinalScore', sortBy: { fieldName: 'CD_score' } };
     
      // Execute the query.
      return publicDB.performQuery(query).then(function(response) {
        if(response.hasErrors) {
          console.error("response errors: " + response.errors[0]);
          return;
        }
       var records = response.records;
        var numberOfRecords = records.length;
        if (numberOfRecords === 0) {
          console.error('No matching items');
          return;
        }
        //self.items(records); // this is per the original, tutorial
        self.items(records.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}));
      });
    };

      container.setUpAuth().then(function(userInfo) {
      console.log("setUpAuth");
      self.fetchRecords(); 
      });
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new LeaderboardViewModel()); 

});
```

Comment: What are the results Safari?

Comment: Same results just in the opposite order (lowest to highest).

Comment: Assuming `records` is an array of plain objects, The `b - a` comparison will return `NaN`. It _could_ be that Safari handles those differently than Firefox (the comparison function passed to `sort` should return a number). Can you give us an example of your data so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: P.S. It feels like this API you're using should take care of the sorting. But if you want to do it client side anyway, here's [a QA about sorting arrays of objects by one of their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. The data comes back like this:
'code'{"items":
 [
  {"recordName":"A0EAC4B5-DBDD-9DD8-6C13-5765C6CBFF64",
  "recordType":"CD_FinalScore",
  "fields":
   {"CD_score":
    {"value":200,
    "type":"INT64"},
   "CD_submitDate":
    {"value":1639153595598,
    "type":"TIMESTAMP"},
   "CD_userIdentifier":
    {"value":"0001",
    "type":"STRING"},
   "CD_userName":
    {"value":"SomeoneElse",
    "type":"STRING"}
  },
 ]
}
'code'

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from [user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291) (particularly in the link provided), I changed the sort to the following:

```
self.items(records.sort(function(a, b) {
          return parseFloat(b.fields.CD_score.value) - parseFloat(a.fields.CD_score.value);
        }));
```

And this appears to be working in both browsers (Firefox and Safari).